# Missing argument 2 for Controller:update() - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, crud

I guess I have an error in my route but I started and I do not find the solution.
When I submit my edit form, i have this error : `Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\Admin\SportController::update()`
My controller :

```
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin');
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    // Récupère tous les sports
    $sports = Sport::all();

    // Charge la vue et passe la liste des sports en paramètre
    return view('admin.sports.index')
        ->with('sports', $sports);    
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('admin.sports.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    // process the login
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)
                               ->withInput();
    }

    Sport::create($request->all());

    Session::flash('message', 'Félicitation, vous avez crée un sport !');
    return redirect('/admin/sports'); 
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    // get the nerd
    $sport = Sport::find($id);

    // show the edit form and pass the nerd
    return view('admin.sports.edit')->with('sport', $sport);    }

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    // process the login
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)
                               ->withInput();
    }
        $sport = Sport::find($id);
        $sport->name= Input::get('name');
        $sport->save();

        Session::flash('message', 'Félicitation, vous avez mis à jour un sport !');
        return redirect('/admin/sports');  
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

My routing :

```
Route::resource('/admin/sports', 'Admin\SportController@index');
Route::resource('/admin/sports/create', 'Admin\SportController@create');
Route::POST('/admin/sports', 'Admin\SportController@store');
Route::get('/admin/sports/edit/{id}','Admin\SportController@edit');
Route::put('/admin/sports','Admin\SportController@update')->name('admin.sports.update');
```

My view : edit.blade.php

```
{{ Html::ul($errors->all()) }}

{{ Form::model($sport, array('route' => array('admin.sports.update', $sport->id), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('name', 'Nom') }}
    {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>
<div class="right-align">
    {{ Form::submit('Valider', array('class' => 'btn btn-flat')) }}
    <a class="btn btn-flat" href="{{ URL::to('admin/sports') }}">Annuler</a>
</div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Thank you for your help.
Peter.

Comment: Why are you doing the resource controller as `Route::resource('/admin/sports', 'Admin\SportController@index');`? Look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers and Partial Resources if you want to exclude routes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change route to this to catch an ID:

```
Route::put('/admin/sports/{id}','Admin\SportController@update')->name('admin.sports.update');
```

Answer (score 1):

In your routes you have:

```
Route::resource('/admin/sports', 'Admin\SportController@index');
```

For resource controllers you don't specify a method, just the controller it does the rest for you.  So when you do:

```
Route::resource('/admin/sports', 'Admin\SportController');
```

You get the following:

```
Method    |         Uri            |         Name         |          action 
GET|HEAD  | admin/sports           | admin.sports.index   | Admin\SportController@index
POST      | admin/sports           | admin.sports.store   | Admin\SportController@store
DELETE    | admin/sports/{id}      | admin.sports.destroy | Admin\SportController@destroy
PUT|PATCH | admin/sports/{id}      | admin.sports.update  | Admin\SportController@update
GET|HEAD  | admin/sports/{id}/edit | admin.sports.edit    | Admin\SportController@edit
```

With that it looks like you're not passing the id to the route.  Change your `Form::model` to:

```
Form::model($sport, array('route' => array('admin.sports.update', array('id', $sport->id)), 'method' => 'PUT'))
```

The 2nd parameter should be an array of route parameters